# Suppress a page of crystal report that contains data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a report that is a combination of "Summary" and "Detail" reports. The data in the Detail section is in a subreport. Since this data is identical to the Summary section when there is only one record the client doesn't want to see the Detail section with only one record.

I can suppress headers, footers, pages without data but cannot find out how to suppress a page with data. Any help would be appreciated.

This needs more details. We have a Summary report and a Detail report. A client wanted them combined. We now have a Detail report with Headers, footers, sub reports etc. This detail report has Report Header sections and each section contains a section or sub report of the Summary report. When run this gives a Summary report, page break and the Detail report. I've tried conditionally suppressing the Detail sections when there was only one record. However, that leaves me with a blank last page that I cannot suppress.
I'm only curious if this can be done as the client has withdrawn their request ending my actual need.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean parameter to your report. If your report data has one record set its value to true. Right click your subreport -> Format Object. Check the Suppress checkbox. Click the formula button to the right of the checkbox.

```
if <name of your parameter> then
   formula = true
else
   formula = false
end if
```

I'm using Basic syntax in CR formula editor